# Performance counter MSSQLInstance\SQL Errors\Errors/sec\Info Errors whats in it?

Tags: sql-server, perfmon

Im wondering what kind of errors would show up in the:

> SQL Errors\Errors/sec\Info errors

performance counter. I read the [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188237.aspx) it just states:

> Information related to error messages that provide information to
>   users but do not cause errors.

Anyone can shed some light on this, examples of what errors might show up here is more than welcome.

Comment: I haven't analyzed the counter myself, but this seems self-explanatory; I suspect it tracks warnings that don't generate actual errors, like the one you get from `sp_rename` or the one about null value eliminated from grouping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this counter and for info errors the following increased the counter (not an exhaustive list):
connect, shrink, backup,script database, modify stored proc, select top 1000 rows, new query, using autosense, starting profiler, stopping trace, activity monitor, new login,
pulling up properties for a login, database, or the server.

User Errors:
Messages in the query results when there is incorrect syntax, or table doesn't exist, that sort of thing.
Taking a database offline or bringing a database online.
Killing a process.

Interesting notes:
starting Job Activity Monitor generated both User and Info.
Starting a job generated both User and Info.
Changing a server option (max server memory) did not increase the counter.

Answer (score 2):

I dug a little deeper myself and it seems that the definition of information errors is errors with severity 10 according to [the documentation of Severity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937483%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and found my specific "Info errors" by profiling on the [User Error Message Event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190953.aspx).  In my case it was database context switches with the message:

> Changed database context to 'DBNAME'

and language changes with the message

> Changed language setting to us_english

And a few of the ones that @aaron-bertrand mentions

Comment: You can simulate this yourself with e.g. `RAISERROR('Info "error"',0,1);`